# How use code to configure Spring cloud gateway supported GatewayFilter like SecureHeaders

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring cloud gateway has many GatewayFilters like AddRequestHeader、SecureHeaders,use configure file like application.yaml is easy to use，but how use this GatewayFilters in java code?

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: route-1
          uri: http://localhost1:5230
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
          filters:
            - SecureHeaders
```

Current I use the follow code to configure

```java
route("route-1", predicateSpec -> predicateSpec.path("/api/**")
                .uri("http://localhost:5230")
                .filter(new SecureHeadersGatewayFilterFactory(new SecureHeadersProperties()).apply(new Object())))
```

Has more better solution？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
route("route-1", predicateSpec -> predicateSpec.path("/api/**")
                .filters(f -> f.secureHeaders()).uri("http://localhost:5230")
```